Is there a way to generate a helm install script from a ConfigMap?
I have a ConfigMap for a nginx ingress controller. Are there any commands I can use that can generate a helm install script for the ConfigMap?
Clarification: I was wondering if there is some way to generate from a ConfigMap a helm install script, an install ingress shell script. There may not be such a thing. Just asking. It would be a nice feature.

Please clarify what output you're expecting... If you have only a configmap and nothing else, you'd use kubectl apply, not Helm. To use Helm, you need a Chart.yaml and some values

You want to install a configmap using a Helm chart, or have a script in a ConfigMap that installs a Helm chart?

It is not possible to directly generate a Helm install script from a ConfigMap. But you can create a Helm chart that uses the ConfigMap. ConfigMaps allow you to decouple configuration artifacts from image content to keep containerized applications portable.
Create test-chart
Create templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
 name: my-config
 labels:
   app: {{ template "app.prefix" . }}
data:
 application.conf: |-
{{ .Files.Get "config/application.config" | nindent 4 }}

and provide your own values.yaml
The Helm is looking for the "config" under the "templates" folder.
Try moving the config folder under templates:
   /chart
     /templates
       my-config-map.yaml
       /config
         application.config

or change (.Files.Glob "config/") to   (.Files.Glob "../config/")
Finally Install chart / use --dry-run Go to main directory ~/test-chart, where you have files like below charts  Chart.yaml  configmap  templates  values.yaml
Now you can helm install chart or use --dry-run option before, to check how configuration YAMLs would look like. You have to display what YAML gets executed by Helm using the: --dry-run --debug options at the end of helm install command. there is controller executed with the: --configmap={namespace-where-the-nginx-ingress-is-deployed}/{name-of-the-helm-chart}-nginx-ingress-controller. In order to load your ConfigMap you need to override it with your own (check out the namespace).

That answers my question! Thank you!
